# Comparing indexes inside of a loop

Tags: php

In my PHP code I have the following code:

```
function readPopulateArray($name) {
    $you = explode(",", readSetUser($name));
    $singles = fopen("singles.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file");

    //print_r($line[]);

    while(!feof($singles)) {
        $lineRead = fgets($singles);

        $matches = explode(",", $lineRead);
        if(($matches[0] != $you[0]) && ($matches[1] != $you[1]) && ($matches[3] == $you[3]) && ($matches[4] == $you[4])&& ($matches[5] <= $you[5] && $matches[6] >= $you[6])) 
        {
            echo $lineRead;
        }
    }
```

}

The purpose of the above snippet is to compare $you, with possible $matches. This occur within the if statement, and for testing purposes I just want to echo the $lineRead. However, when I run it I run into the following error:

> **"Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/practice/matches-submit.php on line 47"**

Line 47 is the line where the if-statement is at. I am currently just learning php, however, I am confused as to why I am getting this error because I know that I can easily access the indexes of $matches and $you by just calling $matches[0] which will return the name, $matches[1] the gender, etc. is this not the way in which one compares array components to one another in php?

I have seen mention of array_map, but I do not need a simple yes/no type of comparison, rather it does involve a bit more.

Edit: Sample of how singles.txt looks like:

```
Ada Lovelace,F,96,ISTJ,Linux,24,99
Adele Goldberg,F,65,ENFJ,Windows,50,70
Anakin Skywalker,M,27,INTJ,Linux,15,30
Angry Video Game Nerd,M,29,ISTJ,Mac OS X,1,99
Anita Borg,F,54,ISFP,Windows,41,55
Barbara Liskov,F,71,ESFJ,Mac OS X,41,76
Bill Gates,M,52,INTJ,Windows,2,99
Bill Joy,M,54,ENFP,Linux,50,70
...
```

Comment: any special reason you're not using a database? and, text files are so much work compared to a db.

Comment: would need to see a sample of singles.txt, to be able to help

Comment: Error tells you that $matches[3] or $you[3] don`t exist.
Print_r($matches) and $you variables, to check what they returns.

Comment: Thing is i know they exist since I access them via a simple echo $matches[3] for example. As for a text file and not a database; it is an intro web class and the professor has yet to cover DBs and supplied us with this file instead.

Comment: So if you are sure $matches[3] exists then problem is with $you[3]. Just check out variable and show us what is returns.

Answer (score 0):

You got this issue because the index does not exists.

You did an explode. ok. But if you have only 3 results (ex: 1, 2, 3) ... so you cannot read the `$matches[>2]`.

Solutions:

1.Check if the offset/index exists:

```
<?php 
$matches = explode(',', 'A,B,C,D');
if( isset($matches[3]) ) {
  echo $matches[3]; // here 'D';
}
if( isset($matches[5]) ) {
  echo $matches[5]; // here the result does not exists;
}
if( count($matches) > 2 ) { // multiple checks 
  echo $matches[0], $matches[1];
}
```

2.You can use a little tips, and add some extra 'coma' after the value:

```
<?php 
$matches = explode(',', 'A,B,C,D' . ',,,,');
```

So, you will always have some results. Here, I added 4x, so, I can read index 0/1/2/3 witout any issues

3.Last thing (you should start with this !), try to debug your values ahd check if this is the expected behavior:

```
<?php 
$matches = explode(',', $lineRead);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Found the issue with the index, turns out there was a rogue new line.